# Overflow action item over normal item in the split actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

[image: Actionbar Overflow problem]

I am using split actionbar and 5 items total at the bottom and 3 of them are set as an actionItem. But the problem is that the overflow item is above the normal item.

Here is the xml and I am not doing anything at the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item 
    android:id="@+id/item_solve"
    android:title="@string/button_coz"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:enabled="false"
    />

<item 
    android:id="@+id/item_report"
    android:title="@string/button_report"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:actionViewClass="com.sorusana.android.app.view.ReportCompoundButton"
    android:enabled="false"
    />

<item 
    android:id="@+id/item_kutu"
    android:title="@string/box_add"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:enabled="false"
    />

<item 
    android:id="@+id/item_delete"
    android:title="@string/delete_question"
    android:enabled="false"
    />

<item 
    android:id="@+id/item_see_answer"
    android:title="@string/see_answer"
    android:enabled="false"
    />
</menu>
```

Comment: I think you need the `ifRoom` instead of `always` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your always attribute the mistake. Try to replace this by ifRoom

Comment: ok but I think there is enough place for 3 items and an overflow icon. When I do what you said, it displays only 2 actionitems.

Comment: It's normal, your third item have not enough place to show him with text. The documentation say it's not good to use always attribute. Or, in your case, for the thir item, remove the withText attribute and it fix it.